# How to set mutiple words variable from command line input in C shell

Tags: shell, variables, argv

I'm writing a script to search for a pattern in file. For example

*scriptname pattern file1 file2 filenN*

I use for loop to loop through arguments argv, and it does the job if all arguments are supplied. However if only one argument is supplied (in that case pattern ) it should ask to input file name or names, and then check for pattern.  How I can set variable to include multiple words  input from command line so I can use it in loop. Or even better is it possible to assign command line input to argv, so I don’t have to use the same loop twice only because it is different  variable name  (one to loop through argv if more than on argument, and second to loop through filenames variable if only one argument supplied). Below is the part of my script which is causing problem:

```
set pattern = $1 
if ($#argv == 1) then
    echo "Enter name of files"
    set filenames = $< #how I can set it to accept more than word?
endif
```

Comment: First, if it's at all possible, you should avoid using csh. It's stuck in the stone age.

Comment: I know but this is what is used at uni and unfortunately we have to learn it

Comment: What is the result of `set filenames = $<` if you `echo $filenames` after entering `file1 file2 file3`? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: It is my fault.  For some reason I deleted white space after =, so set filename =$< was giving my syntax error, and I haven’t noticed the mistake. Shame on me. Thanks for help Dennis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift` and `$argv`

```
#!/bin/csh
set pattern = $1
echo $pattern
shift
set remainder = "$argv"
echo $remainder
```

And running it:

```
% ./demo a b c
a
b c
```

Comment: It answers the second part of my question, but if there is only one argument provided, I need to get additional input from keyboard. If I type during the execution of the script missing name of files (not provided as argument): 

file1 file2 file3

I would like to set remainder to store file1 file2 file3. For example: 

echo"Enter name of files" 

set remainder= $< 

echo $remainder 

Output: file1 file2 file3